# Access the icon of a marker?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

How can I call the marker icon of the google maps API for android? The Title you can call with `getTitle()` but it does not work with the Icon... What is the best way to do if I want to ask if the Icon is a certain drawable?

Answer (score 0):

You must use [`MarkerOptions.getIcon()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions#getIcon()).

Comment: Could you give me an example if the Marker I want to ask for the Icon has the Name 'marker'?